# How to save table in opencart module?

Tags: opencart2.x

I am try this code on
admin/view/template/module/test.tpl

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-featured" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-featured" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
<table id="modules" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php $module_row = 0; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($test_modules as $test_module) { ?>
                    <tr id="module-row<?php echo $module_row; ?>">
                      <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="test_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo $test_module['name']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>
                      <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$('#module-row<?php echo $module_row; ?>').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $module_row++; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="1"></td>
                      <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="addModule();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_module_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var module_row = <?php echo $module_row; ?>;

    function addModule() {
        html  = '<tr id="module-row' + module_row + '">';
        html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="test_module[' + module_row + '][name]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#module-row' + module_row  + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('#modules tbody').append(html);

        module_row++;
    }
    //--></script>
```

and try this code on admin/controller/module/test.php

```
<?php
class ControllerModuleTest extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('module/test');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('extension/module');

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
                $this->model_extension_module->addModule('test', $this->request->post);
            } else {
                $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
            }


            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }


        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

        $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');
        $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');

        $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
        $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
        $data['button_module_add'] = $this->language->get('button_module_add');
        $data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
            $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
        } else {
            $data['error_name'] = '';
        }


        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );

        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('module/test', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
            );
        } else {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('module/test', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], 'SSL')
            );
        }

        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/test', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
        } else {
            $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/test', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], 'SSL');
        }

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

        if (isset($this->request->get['module_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
            $module_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($this->request->get['module_id']);
        }

        $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

        if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
            $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
        } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
            $data['name'] = $module_info['name'];
        } else {
            $data['name'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
            $data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
        } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
            $data['status'] = $module_info['status'];
        } else {
            $data['status'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->post['test_module'])) {
            $test_modules = $this->request->post['test_module'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['test_id'])) {
            $test_modules = $this->config->get('test_module');
        } else {
            $test_modules = array();
        }

        $data['test_modules'] = array();

        foreach ($test_modules as $test_module) {


            $data['test_modules'][] = array(
                'name'      => $test_module['name']
            );
        }

        $this->load->model('design/layout');

        $data['layouts'] = $this->model_design_layout->getLayouts();

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/test.tpl', $data));

    }

    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/test')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 64)) {
            $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }

}
```

But after save it not saved the values of table .

I am not getting whats the wrong in this code.

Any one please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please give full code of your `tpl` file. If it's full code then it won't work as there is no form that submits the data.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Full code of tpl file is added @ Ved Pandya

Answer (score 0):

There is two mistakes in your code
1st - Opencart version 2 don't have add module option to layout option in modules. It's moved to layout now. So you can remove your code now,

2nd - In this version to save values to config your module/ shipping/ payment or others extensions input type name must have prefix of module name so your name must be "test_name" here.